# MapView control from Arcgis portal

Tags: .net, wpf, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

I am developing a wpf application with arcgis runtime sdk for .net 100.2.1.
I have a MapView control on a page and it's working fine.
The namespace of MapView control is xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013".

My company has a Arcgis Portal.
I want to change the namespace of MapView control into my Arcgis Portal.
But I don't know how.

Anybody knows how to ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The xmlns namespace isn't related to the portal. It's merely an XML namespace that points to where the mapview controls lives (similar to "using" in C#).
To access your portal look at the ArcGISPortal class instead. It has code for signing in, searching, querying etc. Those APIs will allow you to find Maps you can adding to the MapView's Map property. Look in the samples repository for examples how to do this.